# ArrayList not show in jsp page when used servlet , and DAO

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, dao

I have create Arraylist in DAO and this list used in  servlet. The result of array list shown in jsp page.

**DAO**

```
package com.dao;

import com.database.DBConnection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListDAO {
    String status=null;
    Connection con= null;
    PreparedStatement pst=null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    private DBConnection conn;

    public ListDAO() {
        con = DBConnection.getConnection();
    }

    public  ArrayList<String> getAllUser() throws SQLException {

        ArrayList<String> allUser = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            String queryList = "SELECT name, last_name, zip, phone_no, start_time, end_time, quantity," +
                               "type, order, logo FROM Database.user_info";

            pst = con.prepareStatement(queryList);

            rs = pst.executeQuery();

              while (rs.next()) {

                allUser .add(rs.getString("name"));
                allUser .add(rs.getString("last_name"));
                allUser .add(rs.getString("zip"));
                allUser .add(rs.getString("phone_no"));
                allUser .add(rs.getString("start_time"));
                allUser .add(rs.getString("end_time"));
                allUser .add(rs.getString("quantity"));
                allUser .add(rs.getString("type"));
                allUser .add(rs.getString("order"));
                allUser .add(rs.getString("logo"));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally {
            if(rs!=null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch(SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
            }
            if(pst!=null) {
                try {
                    pst.close();
                } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
            }
            if(con!=null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch(SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
            }
        }
        return allUser;
    }
}
```

This arraylist pass in the servlet which given below:

**Servlet**

```
package com.servlet;

import com.dao.ListDAO;
import com.database.DBConnection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/checkLogin")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    Connection con= null;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        ListDAO Vendors = new ListDAO();

        if(!userValidate.equals("FALSE")) {

               //Login verified user

            try {
                con = DBConnection.getConnection();
            ArrayList<String> allUser = Vendors.getAllUser();

            request.setAttribute("allUser", allUser); // Will be available as ${allUser} in JSP
            System.out.println(allUser);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("userProfile.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
            catch (SQLException ex) {
              throw new ServletException("Cannot obtain allUser from Database", ex);
            }     
        }
        else {
               response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        }
    }
}
```

And the userProfile.jsp page in which i want to show the ArrayList which is given below:

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${allUser}">
    <div class="col-md-5">
          <img src="Resources/images/logo/logo1.jpg" alt="Logo1">
          <h2>${user.name} ${user.last_name}</h2>
          <p>${user.zip}, ${user.phone_no}, ${user.start_time}, ${user.end_time}</p>
          <p>${user.quantity}, ${user.type}, ${user.order}, ${user.logo}</p>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

The problem is that the whole Array List is in single array, that's why problem to show the array in jsp page. I want to display the individual record of each user(each have 10 thing to display) separately. Can anyone tell me at which place I have did wrong thing.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code? work you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

In Your JSP, you're using

```
${user.name} ${user.last_name}
```

So, that means that the JSP expects each element of the list to be an object with the following methods:

```
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public String getLast_name() {
    return this.lastName;
}
```

But that's not what the list contains. The list is a `List<String>`. It should be a `List<User>`. You should also respect the Java naming conventions BTW. So, change your code to

```
        while (rs.next()) {
            User user = new User();
            user.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            user.setLastName(rs.getString("last_name"));
            ...
            allUser.add(user);
        }
```

That way, each row of the resultset becomes a User object.

Comment: additionally, your `ListDAO` constructor is leaking a connection

Comment: I have try your suggestion and it work partially. I have create a bean class in which make a object and their setter and getter function, and create object of bean in DAO (as you say)in while loop and call the function. The all list parameter shown in jsp except the "name". When  i write ${user.name}  in jsp page, it show the blank page. All data will be display except the "name".

Comment: Then there must be a bug in your code (or the name is indeed null/blank in the database). But without seeing the code, how could I help?